# How to compute a lat/long coordinate between two other coordinates using the Haversine formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

I have two sets of latitude and longitude coordinates, $A$ and $B$. I would like to "interpolate" another coordinate $C$ along the orthodromic line connecting $A$ and $B$ that is $d$ meters away from $A$ in the direction $B$.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the *line connecting* $A$ to $B$? The orthodromic?

Comment: Yes, the orthodrome. I'll clarify in the post

Answer (score 0):

As you consider the orthodromic to join $A$ to $B$, you can compute along the great circle a point at distance $d$ from $A$ on that great circle. With the 3d coordinates of that point, you can compute latitude and longitude.

Comment: How would I convert 3D coordinates to latitude and longitude? My apologies, I'm pretty novice still on these subjects

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116658/faster-numpy-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinate-conversion if you’re looking to write a computer program.